# Special character doesn't output correctly

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$line = 'ABBEKÅS';
echo 'word is '.$line.PHP_EOL;
for($i=0;$i<strlen($line);$i++){
    echo 'char '.$line[$i].PHP_EOL;
}
```

The result is:

```
word is ABBEKÅS
char A
char B
char B
char E
char K
char ?
char ?
char S
```

Why does the word look good while the single character doesn't?
I have tried to convert both to utf-8 and ISO both none helped. This is what I tried:

```
$line = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $line);
```

and

```
$line = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $line);
```

The result is still the same.

Comment: Because you're assuming that each character is only a single byte in your for loop (your'e iterating a byte at a time, not a character at a time), and your Å is a multi-byte character

Answer (score 1):

Because you're assuming that each character is only a single byte in your for loop (you're iterating a **byte** at a time, not a **character** at a time), and your `Å` is a multi-byte character.

If you need to break multi-byte strings into segments/characters, use PHP's [multibyte string functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)

```
for($i=0;$i<mb_strlen($line);$i++){
    echo 'char '.mb_substr($line, $i, 1).PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/KKQX1)

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to retrieve the character with mb_substr. Like this:

```
$line = 'ABBEKÅS';
echo 'word is '.$line.PHP_EOL;
for($i=0;$i<strlen($line);$i++){
    echo mb_substr($line, $i, 1).PHP_EOL;
}
```